# How to add non MVC (html content) to an MVC site?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

**Given**
I have a current MVC site but need to add support for non-MVC content.  In particular the output from SandCastle Help File Builder Help web content.

**What's been tried**

Following tips from S.O. I created a new MVC site with Empty Template just to see how it's done, I created all the folders in the HTML site and populated content by copying files.  I made sure that the images Build Action was Content, Copy if newer.

There are no controllers in the MVC site so I had to alter the Route.Config file as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Default",
 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The action = "Index" resolves Index.html and it does populate all the pages. Notice there's no controller in MapRoute above.

But Images don't show, which I believe has something to do with routing. 
 The Get from each image after page loads looks like this:

```
 Request URL:http://TheSite/media/SomeImage.PNG
```

Where media is the folder where the images are located.

The actual http content that generates that link is this...

```
../media/TestDrillDown.PNG
```

The sites'index.html has this statement from SHFB.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.replace("html/1bb0066d-655c-4883-8045-81f006f3adc8.htm")
</script>
```

which redirects to this page in the browser automatically showing the content correctly.

```
URL:http://localhost:50212/html/1bb0066d-655c-4883-8045-81f006f3adc8.htm
```

**Question**
What must I do to get the images to show and stop showing a 404 (Not found) error.

**What hasn't worked**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute({"{resource}.png");
routes.IgnoreRoute({"media/{resource}.png");
routes.IgnoreRoute({"../media/{resource}.png");
routes.IgnoreRoute({"{resource}.{*png}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a dummy, when I copied in the PNG images somehow I didn't get them all, once that was done and using the config above the Index.html file found them... which is interesting, this is how I think it works...

The redirect in the Index.html page took the link to the /html folder which existed in the MVC site with NO controller.  The files in the /html folder referred to the images "../media/image.png" which was correct for the folder structure.  The returned "Gets" for those images came back as "/media/image.png" which indeed was correct because the image.png was in the media folder off the root... So just the mapping above was all that was needed.  No ignore routes and no controller.... I now have a new issue but I'll post a new question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding a `<location>...</location>` configuration element for your media folder, enabling anonymous authentication.  Something like this in your web.config:

```
<location path="media">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```